# Append param to current URL with view helper in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, zend-route, view-helpers

In my layout-script I wish to create a link, appending *[?|&]lang=en* to the current url, using the url view helper. So, I want this to happen:

http://localhost/user/edit/1 => http://localhost/user/edit/1?lang=en
  http://localhost/index?page=2 => http://localhost/index?page=2&lang=en

I have tried the solution suggested [Zend Framework: Append query strings to current page url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519360/zend-framework-append-query-strings-to-current-page-url), accessing the router directly, but that does work.

My layout-script contains:

```
<a href="<?=$this->escape( $this->url( array('lang'=>'en')) )?>">English</a>
```

If the *default* route is used, it will append */lang/en*, but when another route is used, nothing is appended at all.
So, is there any way to do this with in Zend without me having to parse the url?

**Edit**
Sorry for my faulty explanation. No, I haven't made a custom router. I have just added other *routes*. My bad. One route that doesn't work is:

```
$Routes = array(
    'user' => array(
        'route' => 'admin/user/:mode/:id',
        'defaults' => array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'user', 'mode'=>'', 'id' => 0)
    )
);

foreach( $Routes as $k=>$v ) {
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route($v['route'], $v['defaults']);
    $router->addRoute($k, $route);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered adding `lang` to your custom routes with a default lang if none is specified?

Comment: Yes, I have considered it. But I don't want the lang to be passed on every request, reverting back to the default if not. In my bootstrap I am checking if a lang is passed, if so I store it in the session. Also, it would be nice not having to add lang to every route.

Comment: easiest way - store last request within session, add controller/action to switch language.  It should redirect back to previous request fetched from session or to mainpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upd:

You must add wildcard to your route or define 'lang' parameter explicitly.

```
'admin/user/:mode/:id/*'
```

Additionally, according to your comment, you can do something like this:

```
class controllerplugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    function routeShutdown($request)
    {
        if($request->getParam('lang', false) {
            //store lang
            Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->setGlobalParam('lang', NULL); //check if this will remove lang from wildcard parameters, have no working zf installation here to check.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. A custom route. Not router. I've edited and added one of the routes that fails to show my lang param.

Comment: @ascherer yeah. I know at least two dozen ways to break route )

Comment: Sorry for the delayed accept. Yes, your solution does work for me. Especially your addition. Thanks!